# Funções em Javascript

Tags: javascript

Galera, meu código ta funcionando, só que ta bagunçado, se eu tentar organizar em funções ele para de funcionar:

Assim funciona:

```
var navbar = document.getElementById('nav');
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var posicaoy = window.pageYOffset;
  console.log(posicaoy);
  navbar.style.backgroundColor = posicaoy == 0 ? "transparent" : "white";

  //outras coisas aqui...
});
```

Assim não funciona:

```
var navbar = document.getElementById('nav');
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var posicaoy = window.pageYOffset;
  console.log(posicaoy);

 function mudaNav(){
  navbar.style.backgroundColor = posicaoy == 0 ? "transparent" : "white";
 }
 function mudabla1(){
  //Codigo aqui
 }

 function mudabla2(){
  //Codigo aqui
 }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Alguns problemas com o código:

1) Você está declarando funções dentro de um `lambda` (função anônima).

Se você vai mesmo utilizar funções declaradas, deve deixá-las fora do evento que está adicionando (`addEventListener`).

2) Deve-se ter atenção é para o escopo da variável. No seu exemplo, `navbar` não está disponível dentro do escopo de `mudaNav()`

Comment: Muito bom, irei verificar, eu estou trabalhando com muitos escopos globais, preciso ajustar isso.

Comment: se estiver usando jQuery, experimente usar custom plugins

Comment: Estou usando js puro, estava ficando muito dependente do Jquery, mas obg pela dica.

Answer (score 2):

Você parece estar tendo um problema na compreensão de escopo e argumentos de funções.

```
document.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  mudaNav(window.pageYOffset);
});

function mudaNav(posY) { // precisa receber como argumento
  var navbar = document.getElementById('nav'); // é melhor ter no mesmo escopo
  navbar.style.backgroundColor = (posY == 0) ? "transparent" : "white";
}

function mudabla1(){
  //Codigo aqui
}

function mudabla2(){
  //Codigo aqui
}
```

Comment: Como no C++ eu não deveria declarar as funções antes de chamá-las, ou o JavaScript já é assíncrono por default?

Comment: Javascript é assíncrono por padrão e todas as declarações de variáveis e funções sempre serão "movidas" para o topo script pelo interpretador, tornando-as disponíveis logo no começo da execução do escopo.